# split is not a function react js

Tags: reactjs

```
deleteImages = (images, index, onComplete) => {
    const deleteAgain = (images, index, onCompleted) => 
    this.deleteImages(images, index, onCompleted);

    let splited_link = images[index].split("/")
    let name = splited_link[splited_link.length - 1].split("?")[0].replace("banners%2F", "");

    console.log(name)
  }
```

Hello guys.

Guys please help i am junior. Error in my this code.

```
Uncaught TypeError: images[index].split is not a function
    at HomeFragment.deleteImages (HomeFragment.js:375:1)
    at delete (HomeFragment.js:480:1)
```

split is not a function
split is not a function

Comment: what are the values in your `images`?

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/marly-b3b4e.appspot.com/o/banners%2Fbannerg1o122le1f8.jpg?alt=media&token=276fd629-95b5-47f7-99ed-c7dd6c9ec3a4

Answer (score 1):

The method `split` is [only available for `strings`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp). So this error will occur every time you try to call it in a variable that is not a `string`.

In your case, you probably are trying to access an `index` that is not in the array `images`, or inserted something that is not of type `string` in `images`.

Try to log what is in the variable right before the error:

```js
  deleteImages = (images, index, onComplete) => {
    const deleteAgain = (images, index, onCompleted) => 
    this.deleteImages(images, index, onCompleted);

    console.log(images[index], index, images.length); // this will do
    let splited_link = images[index].split("/")
    let name = splited_link[splited_link.length - 1].split("?")[0].replace("banners%2F", "");

  }
```

Examples of what can be happening:

```js
const images = ['a', 'b', 1]
images[1].split() // Everything works fine
images[2].split() // Error because index 2 is a integer
images[3].split() // Error because index 3 do not exist in images
```

Comment: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/marly-b3b4e.appspot.com/o/banners%2Fbannerg1o122le1f8.jpg?alt=media&token=276fd629-95b5-47f7-99ed-c7dd6c9ec3a4

Comment: try to add the `console.log` before the `splited_link` and check what is the last value logged

Comment: this code return console.log(images[index]);

Comment: {banner: 'firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/marly-…=media&token=51b74afe-0025-426d-b504-df93023353ba'} banner: "firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/marly-b3b4e.appspot.com/o/…" [[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: can you please share your complete response of images?

Comment: @BegencgeldiGeldiev a print of the console would be better. But what I can see now is that `images` is an array of objects. So `split` is not available for them. What you probably want is to access a `string` property inside this object.

Eg:
```let splited_link = images[index].banner.split("/")```